# Portrait images are rotated when displayed

Tags: codenameone

Portrait images are rotated when displayed. I found a related issue that was supposedly fixed in github https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/801.

I tried setting
`Display.getInstance().setProperty("normalizeImage", "true");` on startup but that did not work on a Samsung Note 5

Answer (score 1):

The code for doing this was removed for some reason, I've reopened the issue to investigate.

Comment: This rotates to left for me. Reasons unclear

public Image resizeToCard(Image resized)
{
  Image cardMaskImage = getResources().getImage("imageMask.png");
  double aspectRatio = ((double)resized.getWidth())/((double)cardMaskImage.getWidth());
  cardMaskImage=cardMaskImage.scaled(cardMaskImage.getWidth(), (int)(resized.getHeight()/aspectRatio));
  resized = resized.scaled(cardMaskImage.getWidth(), (int)(resized.getHeight()/aspectRatio));
        Object circleMask = cardMaskImage.createMask();
        return resized.applyMask(circleMask);
 }

Comment: What's the source of your image?

Comment: Sry Shai forgot to update here. My issue is resolved as per https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2538